# делаю файт для текстовой рпг на с++ и вывод после функции ненормальный

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class enemy {
    float hp, damage;
public:
    enemy() { hp, damage; }
    void input() {
        cout << "enemy hp" << endl;
        cin >> hp;
        cout << "enemy damage" << endl;
        cin >> damage;
    }
    void debug_output() {
        cout << hp << " " << damage << endl;
    }
    int GetDamage() const {
        return damage;
    }
    void mhp() {
        enemy h;
        hp = hp - h.GetDamage();
    }
    int gethp() const {
        return hp;
    }
};
class hero {
    unsigned int hp, damage, chp;
    int zel_h, zel_s;
public:
    hero() { hp, damage, zel_h, zel_s; }
    void init() {
        chp = hp;
    }
    void use_zel_h() {
        if (hp == chp) {
            zel_h--;
        }
        else {
            zel_h--;
            hp = chp;
        }
    }
    void input() {
        cout << "hero hp" << endl;
        cin >> hp;
        cout << "hero damage" << endl;
        cin >> damage;
        cout << "zelie" << endl;
        cin >> zel_h;
    }
    void debug_output() {
        cout << hp << " " << damage << " " << zel_h << endl;
    }
    void mhp() {
        enemy e;
        hp = hp - e.GetDamage();
    }
    int GetDamage() const {
        return damage;
    }
    int gethp() const {
        return hp;
    }
};
void battle() {
    hero h;
    enemy e;
    string input;
    int flag = 0;//0-hero,1-enemy
    cin >> input;
    if (flag == 0) {
        if (input == "hit") {
            e.mhp();
            flag = 1;
            cout << "hero hp: " << h.gethp() << "|" << "enemy hp: " << e.gethp()<<endl;
        }
        else if (input == "use zel") {
            h.use_zel_h();
            flag = 1;
            cout << "hero hp: " << h.gethp() << "|" << "enemy hp: " << e.gethp() << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        h.mhp();
        flag = 0;
        cout << "hero hp: " << h.gethp() << "|" << "enemy hp: " << e.gethp() << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    hero h;
    enemy e;
    h.init();
    e.input();
    h.input();
    cout << h.gethp() << endl;
    battle();
    
}
```

проблема в том что при выводе здоровья врага в начале оно выводится нормально а после работы функции mhp в обеих классов вывод всегда какой то непонятный здоровье героя -огромное число а здоровье врага всегда 0.

Comment: неправильно вызываете конструкторы `hero() { hp, damage, zel_h, zel_s; }` => `hero() : hp(), damage(), zel_h(), zel_s(){ }`

Comment: А вы вообще понимаете, что `e` здесь `void mhp() {
        enemy e;
        hp = hp - e.GetDamage();
    }` не имеет н малейшего отношения к `e` отсюда `int main() {
    hero h;
    enemy e;
    h.init();`?

Answer (score 0):

```
// ------------- //
// - Enemy.hpp - //
// ------------- //
#ifndef __ENEMY_HPP__
#define __ENEMY_HPP__

#include <iostream>

class Enemy {
public:
    Enemy();
    Enemy(int, int);
    Enemy(int (&data)[]);

    int get_hp() const;
    int get_damage() const;

    void modifyHP(Enemy&);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Enemy&);

protected:
    int hp, damage;
};

#endif

// ------------- //
// - Enemy.cpp - //
// ------------- //

#include "Enemy.hpp"

Enemy::Enemy(): hp(0), damage(0) {}
Enemy::Enemy(int hp, int damage): hp(hp), damage(damage) {}
Enemy::Enemy(int (&data)[]): hp(data[0]), damage(data[1]) {}

int Enemy::get_hp() const { return hp; }
int Enemy::get_damage() const { return damage; }

void Enemy::modifyHP(Enemy& other) { hp -= other.get_damage(); }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Enemy& other) {
    out << "Enemy(";
    out << "hp: " << other.get_hp() << ", ";
    out << "damage: " << other.get_damage() << ")";
    return out;
}

// ------------ //
// - Hero.hpp - //
// ------------ //
#ifndef __HERO_HPP__
#define __HERO_HPP__

#include "Enemy.hpp"

class Hero: public Enemy {
    int hp0, zelie;
    
public:
    Hero();
    Hero(int, int, int);
    Hero(int (&data)[]);

    int get_zelie() const;

    bool useZelie();

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Hero&);
};

#endif

// ------------ //
// - Hero.cpp - //
// ------------ //

#include "Hero.hpp"

Hero::Hero(): Enemy(), hp0(0), zelie(0) {}
Hero::Hero(int hp, int damage, int zelie): Enemy(hp, damage), hp0(hp), zelie(zelie) {}
Hero::Hero(int (&data)[]): Enemy(data), hp0(data[0]), zelie(data[2]) {}

int Hero::get_zelie() const { return zelie; }

bool Hero::useZelie() {
    if (zelie) {
        hp += hp0 / 5;
        --zelie;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Hero& other) {
    out << "Hero(";
    out << "hp: " << other.get_hp() << ", ";
    out << "zelie: " << other.get_zelie() << ", ";
    out << "damage: " << other.get_damage() << ")";
    return out;
}

// ------------ //
// - main.cpp - //
// ------------ //

#include "Hero.hpp"

#include <string>

void scan(int (&data)[], std::string name, int count, const std::string (&strs)[]) {
    std::cout << name << '\n';
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        std::cout << "--> " << strs[i] << ": ";
        std::cin >> data[i];

        if (data[i] <= 0) {
            std::cout << "Input value must be a positive integer\n";
            --i;
        }
    }
    std::cin.clear();
}

bool battle(Hero& hero, Enemy& enemy, std::string& input, bool& key) {
    // -------- //
    // - Hero - //
    // -------- //
    if (input == "hit")
        enemy.modifyHP(hero);
    else if (input == "zelie") {
        if (!hero.useZelie()) {
            std::cout << "All zelies have been used!\n";
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Unknown command!\n";
        return true;
    }
    
    std::cout << enemy << '\n';
    if (enemy.get_hp() <= 0)
        return false;
    key = !key;

    // --------- //
    // - Enemy - //
    // --------- //
    hero.modifyHP(enemy);

    std::cout << hero << '\n';
    if (hero.get_hp() <= 0)
        return false;
    key = !key;
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int hero_data[3], enemy_data[2];

    (void) scan(enemy_data, "Enemy", 2, {"HP", "Damage"});
    (void) scan(hero_data, "Hero", 3, {"HP", "Damage", "Zelie"});

    Hero hero(hero_data);
    Enemy enemy(enemy_data);

    bool key = true;
    std::string input;

    int i = 0;
    do {
        std::cout << "Action " << ++i << ": ";
        std::cin >> input;
    } while(battle(hero, enemy, input, key));

    std::cout << "\n\n";
    if (key)
        std::cout << "Hero wins!\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Enemy wins!\n";
    return 0;
}
```